# Get values from table ready to send to php

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb

I have a table that creates rows when you press the `Add Order Item` It runs a function that appends this:

```
function Add() {
    $('#table-order').append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='order-qty'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='order-desc'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='order-options'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='order-price'/></td>" +
        "<td><span class='btn-save'>Save</span>|<span class='btn-delete'>Delete</span></td>" +
        "</tr>"
    );

    $(".btn-save").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btn-delete").bind("click", Delete);        
}
```

I am looking at some way to get all the input values (excluding the last TD cell).

The idea is: get all the values in an object or an array, split each line as the order willl have multiple rows.
Pass the object as a `$_POST` to php to then send to `mongoDB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through inputs and post collected values when click save button like;

```
var params = [];
$("input").each(function() {
    params.push($(this).attr("class") + "=" + $(this).val())
});

$.ajax({
    url:"your url",
    method: "POST",
    data: params.join("&"),
    success: function(response) {
        //handle response
    }
});
```

You can see sample demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/9pFq4/**